# ERC-20 contract from another contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens, erc-20

I am trying to create contract which can access functions of any ERC-20 standard token contract. At first, I'd like to get balance of given address.

I run private testnet using geth, I have deployed following token contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData) external; }

contract TokenERC20 {

string public name;
string public symbol;
uint8 public decimals = 18;
uint256 public totalSupply;

mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);

constructor(uint256 initialSupply, string tokenName, string tokenSymbol) public {
    totalSupply = initialSupply;
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
    name = tokenName;
    symbol = tokenSymbol;
}

function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
    require(_to != 0x0);
    require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
    require(balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]);
    uint previousBalances = balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to];
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;
    emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    assert(balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to] == previousBalances);
}

function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public {
    _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
}

function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);
    allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
    _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
}

function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    return true;
}

function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData) public returns (bool success) {
    tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
    if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
        spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
        return true;
    }
}

function burn(uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
    totalSupply -= _value;
    emit Burn(msg.sender, _value);
    return true;
}

function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);
    require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
    allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
    totalSupply -= _value;
    emit Burn(_from, _value);
    return true;
}

function () public payable {
    revert();
}

}
```

Everything works fine, I tested it on geth successfuly.

Then I created following contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

contract ERC20 {
function totalSupply() constant returns (uint256 totalSupply);
function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance);
function transfer(address _to, uint _value);
event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint _value);
}

contract TokenChecker {
address private senderAddress;
address private tokenAddress;

constructor(address _tokenAddress) public {
    senderAddress = msg.sender;
    tokenAddress = _tokenAddress;
}

function bal(address _address) public constant returns (uint256 balance) {
    ERC20 token = ERC20(tokenAddress);
    return token.balanceOf(_address);
}

function getThis() public constant returns (address thisAddress) {
    return address(this);
}

function tokenAdrs() public constant returns (address adrs) {
    return tokenAddress;
}

function () public payable {
    revert();
}
}
```

This one was deployed using this JavaScript:

```
var tokenCheckerFactory = eth.contract(COMPILED_WITH_SOLC_ABI)
var tokenCheckerCompiled = "0xCOMPILED_WITH_SOLC_BIN"
var _tokenAddress = "DEPLOYED_TokenERC20_ADDRESS"

var tokenChecker = tokenCheckerFactory.new(_tokenAddress, {from:eth.accounts[0],data:tokenCheckerCompiled,gas:2000000}, function(e, contract){
if(e) {
  console.error(e); // If something goes wrong, at least we'll know.
  return;
}

if(!contract.address) {
  console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");

} else {
  console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
  console.log(contract);
}
})
```

In geth, `getThis()` and `tokenAdrs()` are OK, but theres always 0 returned by `bal()` with any argument:

```
// geth console
> token.balanceOf(eth.accounts[0]) // instance of TokenERC20
2.0999984e+25
> tokenChecker.bal(eth.accounts[0])
0
>
```

What is wrong with my code? Why can't TokenChecker interact with provided ERC-20 contract? Could it even communicate with random ERC-20 token by given its contract address like this? Thank you in advance.

**Edit:** When I omit `constant` at `bal()`, new transaction is submitted, nothing is returned to console. When i start mining, nothing special happens, only info about mining is shown. And `view` returns always 0 too.

Comment: I see have this defined in your code: `^0.4.16;` but you are using features introduced after that version. Not saying this is your solution, but noting it for reference. 

They keyword `constructor` was introduced in 0.4.22 (2018-04-16)

https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/develop/Changelog.md

Comment: I've copied and pasted your code into remix for testing via the JS VM. 

Your `bal()` worked and returned the proper value.

I would assume the problem lies with your JS code, not Solidity. .

Comment: @MSwezey Yes, this is my solution, I'm newcommer to solidity. I've changed version and still nothing. Constructor works, because when I pass argument, save it in constructor and return it from some function, passed address is displayed. I think error is at instantiation of ERC20. I've tried to create instance in constructor and `function tokenSupply() public constant returns (uint256 totalSupply) { return token.totalSupply(); }` and it returns 0 too as if instance of ERC20 didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because bal is set as constant? https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/contracts.html?highlight=constant#constant-state-variables

Comment: When I omit `constant`, new transaction is submitted, nothing is returned to console. When i start mining, nothing special happens, only info about mining is shown.

Comment: And `view` returns always 0 too.

Answer (score 0):

`function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance);` is the problem

I think you must use as follows:
`function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256);`